# Hiding Row based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to hide the fourth row in my spreadsheet based on two values in the same sheet.

Anytime a certain row has values "CO" and "USD," I would like to hide the fourth row. The row placement will differ by the selected parameter. For example, the row might fall into row 2,000 or row 675.

Can someone please help? I am new to vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so assuming that you don't know where "CO" & "USD" are on the sheet, then we will have to find them first before using xQbert's code.

This is how:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Lets find your values
Set oLookin1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange 'Sheet name here
sLookFor1 = "CO"
Set oFound1 = oLookin1.Find(What:=sLookFor1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

Set oLookin2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange 'Sheet name here
sLookFor2 = "USD"
Set oFound2 = oLookin2.Find(What:=sLookFor2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If Not oFound1 Is Nothing And Not oFound2 Is Nothing Then 'make sure the values are found
If oFound1.Row = oFound2.Row Then 'make sure that "CO" & "UDC" are in the same row
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Else
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
Else
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

End Sub
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: Hmm that doesnt seem to be working and i substituted "Sheet1" with "Currency" which is the sheet i am using

Comment: @user3746034 When you say "doesn't seem to be working" what exactly do you mean. Here is a link to a sample sheet: https://db.tt/E1o51pJm It is working!

Comment: So I created a new workbook and used "Sheet 1" as the worksheet. I inserted "CO" and "USD" into row 9 for example. I dumped your code into a new module and ran the macro. Row 4 was still showing.

Comment: What do you mean dumped the code in to a new module and ran the macro? This code should be added in the code of the sheet in which you are inserting "CO" and "USD". Did you try downloading the sample sheet in the link in my comment?

Comment: I did and your right I was using a module to insert the code you posted; however, I went back and transferred the code into the worksheet "Currency" that I was using. The spreadsheet started flickering for about 20 seconds, but still didnt hide row 4. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to download the sheet that I provided in the link? Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes I downloaded the sheet and row 4 is still showing after executing the macro. I'm on excel 2010 if that makes a difference

Comment: Try downloading it again now: https://db.tt/E1o51pJm. As you will notice, Row 4 is already hidden as the words "CO" and "USD" are in Row 9. To test try removing either word and modifying it, and you should have Row 4 reappear. This will happen automatically and you don't have to *execute/run* anything as the code is running an On Sheet Change Event. Let me know if this works.

Comment: If so, then please accept & up vote my answer. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

When learning about VBA I recommend recording a macro doing what you want to do and then review how the macro does it.

Here's the end result when I recorded a macro and made a few changes.  I copied the macro to put the code hiding the row on the change event (selectionchange) of the worksheet. This checks Cell B3 and D3 for the values CO and USD respectively.  If B3 and D3 equal CO and USD, Row 4 is hidden.  When the values change, Row 4 is un-hidden.

[image]

and because of a comment I agree with, I added the `application.enable` events

Comment: Yup, that should do it. +1 You might wanna throw in there `Application.EnableEvents = False` & then `Application.EnableEvents = True` just in case :)

Comment: True I hate screen flicker :D

Comment: So I've actually tried this, but CO and USD are not always going to be on row 3. The problem I'm having is using the right syntax to adjust for non-fixed rows. For example, CO and USD will always be on the same row but they might fall into row 2,000 or row 1,243

Comment: @xQbert It's not so much about screen flicker (although that can happen) it's about the potential of your code triggering itself in a never-ending loop.